# Find elements that match two selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I searched a lot in the net, without an answer.

I want to select a TD elemet with no children AND text="abc". I can do one of them at once but not both.

I've tried something like that:

```
$('#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1').contents().find('td:not(:has(*)),td:contains("abc")')
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
the selection is in an IFrame - maybe this is the problem?

Comment: `.find('td:not(:has(*)):contains("abc")')` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff - it's not working... return length : 0

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/ac5Ns/  So provide relevant HTML.

Comment: The only reason would be rendred HTML to be different in IE10 but seems quite strange... If you don't want to provide relevant HTML, that's ok with me, not *my* issue ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ac5Ns/3/ both in chrome and ie not work. when i added `.contents()` (http://jsfiddle.net/ac5Ns/4/) - works only in chrome

Comment: BUT if it is an iframe, you need to use `contents()` http://jsfiddle.net/ac5Ns/5/  And please be aware of same origin policy, just saying before you said, still doesn't work... PS: didn't see your EDIT in question

Comment: is it work for you in ie? not for me... and yes - it's on the same domain

Comment: stange.. ok i'll keep search.. thanks anyway

Comment: I see there is error on IE coming from access to reloaded iframe, but seems related to jsfiddle, maybe last update, i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td(:has(*))").filter(function() {
return $(this).text().indexOf('abc') === 0;
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1 td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children().length === 0 && $(this).text() === 'abc';
});
```

Comment: You might want to trim the text before checking. There could be leading/trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1').find('td:not(:has(*)),td:contains("abc")');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$('#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1 td:not(:has(*)), #MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ1 td:contains("abc")')
```

Answer (score 0):

a custom selector might also work

```
    $.expr[':'].mySelector = function(elem, index, data){

        var c = elem.childNodes,len=c.length;

        //1- checks that childnodes are NOT element nodes you could opt for (2)
        while(len--){

            if(c[len].nodeType==1)return false;

        }

        /*2- checks that childnodes are ONLY text nodes you could opt for (1)
        while(len--){

            if(c[len].nodeType!=3)return false;

        }
        */

        return (elem.innerText || elem.textContent).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'') == data[3];


    };

    $(function(){


        console.log($('td:mySelector(abc)'));

    });
```